# Would a specific type of animal be capitalized?

Tags: synonyms

I did a project on owls. And I had to name 5 breeds, or species, of owls. But would they be capitalized or not? For example, spotted owls. Is it Spotted Owls or Spotted owls or spotted Owls or just spotted owls?
{The project is already done, I'm not cheating, just checking if I am correct, because i did Spotted Owl}
And the same goes for dogs! Like Golden Retrievers. Capitalized or not? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

There's a pretty big debate about that, actually. I know that Audubon Magazine, for one, recently decided to capitalize every word of a bird's name (Spotted Owl, Roseate Spoonbill, Northern Cardinal, etc.), but in the editor's note announcing the decision, Mark Jannot described how people argued strongly for not capitalizing the names, too. [Here's](http://www.audubonmagazine.org/articles/living/editors-note-case-sensitive) a link to that editor's note, which reads in part:

> I have to be honest: I approached the whole thing as something of a lark. But I quickly realized that everyone else was dead serious. The passionate lowercasers were agog that anyone could argue against standard English usage. The passionate Capitalizers made appeals grounded in the rectitude of the bird-science authorities. Things got heated. Snide remarks were made. Ultimately, I found myself swayed by a simple argument around the observation that an abundance of bird species names include common descriptive adjectives. There are, after all, any number of birds that can be described as a yellow warbler, but a Yellow Warbler is a particular taxonomic species. Capitalizing clears up confusion.

So, to summarize, you probably wouldn't be considered "wrong" either way, but like Jannot points out, capitalization does allow you to avoid any confusion. And as the National Audubon Society could be considered an expert authority on bird terminology, it makes sense to trust its judgment.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'I have to be honest: I approached the whole thing as something of a Lark.?

Answer (score 1):

"spotted owls" would be correct, but their scientific name would be written, "*Strix occidentalis*"

Comment: Yes. Capitalization is precisely spelled out for scientific names: the Genus gets capitalized, and the species does not. Thus, _Homo sapiens_. If there is a proper scientific name, you hafta capitalize it that way. If you're not being precise, however, but talking about common, or garden, variety bird names, then you hafta choose up sides, because there simply are no good rules for capitalization of common names, except in specific writing communities (speech communities are no problem; capital letters are inaudible). Writing is, after all, a very slow technology to adapt.